# You need to authenticate to the WCF(Windows Communication Foundation) service?

Tags: html, ajax, wcf, authentication, passwords

You are developing an application that consumes a Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) service.
The application interacts with the service by using the following code. (Line numbers are included for
reference only.)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lose4.jpg)

You need to authenticate to the WCF service.
What should you do?

Possible answers are [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJs6E.png)

Please can anyone tells me which is the right answer ??? 
I have researched over internet.

Comment: thanks. I appreciate your answer. But it is not the best practice to add username and password at url. Because this user is threatened from hackers. His password is exposed.I think that A is the most suitable solution.